# C#/XNA Stopping Songs In Different GameStates

Tags: c#, audio, menu, xna-4.0, states

I am trying to have music play in my Menu state but cut out after I switch to my Game state.

Comment: now what do you want us to do?

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

The MediaPlayer class has a Play() and Stop() methods. Here you are the MSDN links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer.play.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer.stop.aspx

If I remember correctly, you can do this:

```
// Variable declaration
Song menu_song;
Song game_song;
bool isInMenu; //I'll use this instead of the gamestate as example

//In the LoadContent method:
//remember to add the song to your project. In this case is in 
//a folder called "music"
 Content.Load<Song>("music/menuSongName"); 
 Content.Load<Song>("music/gameSongName"); 

//In Update method:

if (isInMenu) 
{
MediaPlayer.Stop(); //Stop the current audio...
MediaPlayer.Play(menu_song); //...and start playing the next.
}
else
{
MediaPlayer.Stop(); //Stop the current audio
MediaPlayer.Play(game_song); //...and start playing the next.
}
```

I haven't checked this code, if you have some problem please tell me and I'll check it. =)
And it's the same with the gamestates, I think you'll know how to adapt this code to your needs.